# redirect to error page in yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2

i'm still new in yii2.

so, make a simple project which use MVC in yii2 where the project is to output examination result.

what bugging me is, how to redirect to main page as no data found in database?

another one, i get `Undefined offset: 0` which i googled say `mismatch array` and `data not NULL`.

anyhow, here are those code :

controller : StudentController.php

```
public function actionCall()
{         

    $result = $_POST['semester'];
    $result_explode = explode('|', $result);

    $sem = $result_explode[0];
    $tahun = $result_explode[0]." ".$result_explode[1];

    $send = array(
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
        'semester' => $sem ,
        'tahun' => $tahun);

    $model = new Student();


    if(!$data['result']= $model->getDetails($send))
    {
        return $this->render('detail', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render('detail');
    }


}

public function actionSearch()
{         

    return $this->render('searchstudent2');
}
```

model : Student.php

```
public function getDetails($send)
```

{

```
$student = student::find()
       ->select('s.student_name,al.level_matric_no,al.level_semester,al.level_id,s.student_mykad, s.student_address,s.student_postcode,
        s.student_state,ss.subject_code,ss.subject_name,ss.subject_credit_hour,c.course_name,st.taken_session,
        g.Grade_symbol,g.Grade_value,sr.semester_gpa,sr.semester_cgpa,sr.total_point,
        sr.total_credit, sr.semester_count')
       ->from('student AS s')
       ->leftJoin('a_level AS al', '`s`.`student_id` = `al`.`student_id`')
       ->leftJoin('subject_taken AS st', '`al`.`level_id` = `st`.`level_id`')
       ->leftJoin('semester_result AS sr', '`al`.`level_id` = `sr`.`level_id`')
       ->leftJoin('grade AS g', '`g`.`grade_id` = `st`.`grade_id`')
       ->leftJoin('course AS c', '`al`.`level_course_offered` = `c`.`course_id`')
       ->leftJoin('subject AS ss', '`ss`.`subject_id` = `st`.`subject_id`')
       ->where(['al.level_id'=>$send['id']])
       ->andWhere(['sr.semester_count'=>$send['semester']])
       ->andWhere(['st.taken_session'=>$send['tahun']])
       ->asArray()
       ->all();

       return $student;

 }
```

view : searchstudent2.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <h2>Stylish Search Box</h2>
       <div id="custom-search-input">
       <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => Url::to(['student/call']),'options' => ['method' => 'post']]) ?>
                        <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                                <select name="semester">
                                    <option value="1|2012/2013">sem1</option>
                                    <option value="2|2013/2014">sem2</option>
                                    <option value="3|2014/2015">sem3</option>
                                    <option value="4|2015/2016">sem4</option>
                                </select>

                                <br><br>
                            <input type="text" name="id" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                                    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
                    </div>
</div>
```

detail.php

table 1 in detail.php

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
  <th class="tg-yw4l">Nama</th>
  <th class="tg-baqh" colspan="7"><?php echo $result[0]['student_name']; ?></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">Alamat</td>
  <td class="tg-baqh"><?php echo $result[0]['student_address']; echo "&nbsp;". $result[0]['student_postcode']; echo "&nbsp;".$result[0]['student_state'];?></td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="4"></td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">Kemasukan</td>
  <td class="tg-baqh"></td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="4"></td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">No. KP</td>
  <td class="tg-baqh"><?php echo $result[0]['student_mykad']; ?></td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">Sesi</td>
  <td class="tg-baqh"><?php echo $result[0]['taken_session']; ?></td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">Tahun Akademik</td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $result[0]['taken_session']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">No. Matrik</td>
  <td class="tg-baqh"><?php echo $result[0]['level_matric_no']; ?></td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">Fakulti</td>
  <td class="tg-baqh"></td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">Program</td>
  <td class="tg-baqh"><?php echo $result[0]['course_name']; ?></td>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">Semester</td>
  <td class="tg-baqh"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="tg-yw4l">Pinjaman</td>
  <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="7"></td>
</tr>
```

table 2 in detail.php

```
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-031e">BIL</th>
      <th class="tg-031e">KOD</th>
      <th class="tg-031e">SUBJEK</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l">KREDIT</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l">GRED</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l">MATA</th>
      <!-- <th class="tg-yw4l">GPA/CGPA</th> -->
    </tr>

    <?php 
   $bil=0;
   foreach ($result as $details) {
       $bil++;


    ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-031e"><?=$bil?></td>
      <td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $details['subject_code']; ?></td>
      <td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $details['subject_name']; ?></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $details['subject_credit_hour']; ?></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $details['Grade_symbol']; ?></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $details['Grade_value']; ?></td>


    </tr>
     <?php } ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-031e" colspan="2"></td>
      <td class="tg-031e">TOTAL KREDIT</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $details['total_point']; ?></td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l">JUMLAH JAM KREDIT</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="3"><?php echo $details['total_credit']; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you add your sql tables? And also, did you use Gii?

Comment: Please tell me in which line you get Undefined offset: 0

Comment: thanks for the welcome @Jørgen . i'm not using Gii and I use 6 tables. how to post all?

Comment: @RK12 hi. in views\student\detail.php line 17 :

Comment: Hold on with the tables. Are your relations defined in the DB?

Comment: @Jørgen all relation in coding. the reason is, the original DB is combination of many types such as innodbb, myisam...

Comment: what is that line please paste some code from detail.php

Comment: Okey, we could investigate further on your error, but from what i can see you're taking a very non-yii approach to this. I would recommend reading about Gii, Active Record, Relations and other topics on http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/  and learn to use the framework as intended from the developers. It is amazing once you get over that first hurdle and understand how it works :)

Comment: @RK12 i updated in the question

Comment: Sorry i could'nt find it

Comment: @Jørgen i'm using yii2 but not using Gii in my part. this project originally in codeigniter framework. so my task is to convert it to yii2 framework.

Comment: What will you get in $result. Print $result in detail.php

Comment: You should pass $result from controller.

Comment: @RK12 here is the output for detail.php  :  http://prntscr.com/af1eb5

Comment: I was telling you to print your print_r($result) in top of detail.php

Comment: @RK12 exceed 515 characters in this comment..how?

Comment: ok..Just do print_r($result[0]['student_name']);

Comment: @RK12 here :  ixs AzirAn oAqnirAn riizi oAZAr irAni

Comment: Please put !empty condition in line 17. Like this : !empty($data) ? $data : "-"; and try again.

Comment: @RK12 sorry for late reply. i try many times and it still not redirect to main page as no data found in database.

Comment: Change your if statement like this and try :  if(!empty($data['result']) && $data['result'] == $model->getDetails($send))

Comment: @RK12 i will try. for now this project are suspended until further notice from my supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps one by one

1. check $_POST['semester'] and make sure it is not empty
2. check $model->getDetails($send) returns any result or not.

Note: find()-> ...asArray()->all() returns an empty array  if no result found. so check for empty result before for render view.

```
if( !empty($data=$model->getDetails($send)) )
{
    return $this->render('detail', ['viewData'=>$data]);
}
else
{
    return $this->render('_another_view');
    // or redirect to some page or do whatever

}
```

Note: if you send empty $data array to the view and if you use $data[0]['anything']
you will get Undefined offset: 0 error.
so if result is empty then render another view. in your case you are rendering same view 'detail' one with $data another without $data. 
So there is a high chance to get Undefined offset: 0 error.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the advice. i will try. for now this project are suspended until further notice from my supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

If *getDetails* functions doesn't return data, redirect to main page:

```
if ( ($data = $model->getDetails($send)) != null ) {

  return $this->render('detail', ['result' => $data]);

} else {
   // redirect no data
   return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i will try. for now this project are suspended until further notice from my supervisor.

Comment: Try it, and let us know. Choose one to don't leave the question unanswered.